# ClassLoad an Enum type

Tags: java, enums, classloader

How would one go about instantiating an Enum type via a ClassLoader or similar mechanism? (I'm trying to keep everything under the same context classloader for a standalone server application).

I have something like:

```
ClassLoader loader = new CustomClassLoader(parent, libDir);

Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(loader);

// trouble area
Class<?> containerClass = loader.loadClass("com.somepackage.app.Name$SERVER");
```

I had wrongly thought simply loading the Enum would be enough to kick it off (it's private constructor contains startup method calls and what-not).

Doing what I have above does not result in any exceptions, but the JVM just terminates after the last line and the server does not start up.

Obviously doing:

```
containerClass.newInstance();
```

Results in an exception being thrown.

Comment: To avoid all the reflection, I would kick off a thread which uses you new ClassLoader and all the code in it should be natural.

Comment: @PeterLawrey how do you mean? The custom classloader is part of a bootstrapping process in it's own jar, it locates all the necessary libs for the classpath and does some other logic, then starts up the main server application (in another jar).

Comment: Do you have access to the Enum classes code?  You may have to write a public constructor explicitly.

Comment: And when you start a new thread you can give it a ClassLoader to work from without being confused about which class loader will be used by default.

Comment: When you set the class loader, it won't reset any classes already loaded e.g. because they appears in a class you were running.

Comment: Did you try to use `Enum.valueOf( containerClass, "name of an instance")`?

Comment: @RealSkeptic that does seem to be getting thing onto the right track. I lost some generics typing and get compiler warnings, but seems to work. I now have `Class containerClass = loader.loadClass("com.somepackage.app.Name"); Enum.valueOf(containerClass, "SERVER");` both lines get warnings, but I can live with that unless there's a cleaner way.

Comment: Note that I found a simpler solution and added it to my answer.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I'd +1 you again if I could! thank you indeed :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand on my comment, I think the cleanest you'll get is something like this:

```
public static <T extends Enum<T>> T loadEnum(ClassLoader loader, String classBinaryName, String instanceName) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Class<T> eClass = (Class<T>)loader.loadClass(classBinaryName);
    return Enum.valueOf(eClass, instanceName);
}
```

There is really no way to avoid the unchecked cast from `Class<?>` to a proper enum type. But at least the `@SuppressWarnings` is limited in scope.

---

### Edit:

Upon further checking, there is actually a simpler way of achieving what you need, without needing to know the name of an instance and without warnings:

```
Class<?> containerClass = loader.loadClass("com.somepackage.app.Name");
containerClass.getEnumConstants()
```

Answer (score 0):

Loading an enum doesn't cause it to initialize. You have to reference it through either a field reference or a method reference. So even a simple statement like `Name name = Name.SERVER;` or `Name.SERVER.name();` would do the trick.

See section [5.5 Initialization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.5) in chapter [5. Loading, Linking, and Initializing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html) of the Java Virtual Machine Specification.